# email into a list on 2013 SharePoint-online

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, email

I have setup a IT ticketing system in SP (hosted via office 365) and I wanted to make it easier for my employees to send me tickets (sp mobile isn't very friendly)

Is there a way to have an email address that will enter items into a list in SharePoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint Online doesn't support this functionality OOB, but using 3rd party solutions you can do it.  Please check out link "[How to Create HelpDesk on SharePoint Online](http://plumsail.com/blog/2013/12/how-to-create-helpdesk-on-sharepoint-2013online/)" it describes very similar use case.

Comment: Now it is available as ready to use HelpDesk solution for SharePoint Online: https://plumsail.com/sharepoint-helpdesk. I'm part of development team.

Comment: Hi @AntonKhritonenkov! Am I right, that this solution does not work now (because of blocked sandbopx C# code)? Best regards,     Gennady

Comment: @GennadyG, It works well and it will work in feasible future. Only code based sandbox solutions are deprecated. Declarative solutions are fully supported. Please read this article for more information https://plumsail.com/docs/workflow-actions-pack/how-to/Workflow%20Actions%20Pack%20is%20not%20code-based%20sandbox%20solution.html

Answer (score 6):

Office 365 does not support incoming e-mail to lists and libraries. Sorry.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/msonline/en-US/73673deb-04e8-4a27-a825-fe3b58683135/email-enabled-listslibraries-in-sharepoint-office-365?forum=onlineservicessharepoint

There are third party addons which can allow this, but they all cost money.

http://blog.pentalogic.net/2012/08/options-sharepoint-onlineemail-enabled-document-libraries-lists/

Comment: BOOO, but thanks for the quick answer!

Answer (score 5):

With SharePoint Online you cannot enable incoming e-mails on a list, but you can create a site mailbox:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-help/overview-use-a-site-mailbox-to-collaborate-with-your-team-HA103927690.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is a third party Sharepoint app which handles this: http://www.office-cloud-services.com

Answer (score 1):

We have been using [Cloud2050.com's Exchange to SharePoint connector](http://cloud2050.com). It is a cloud based service and very easy to set up. You can set up multiple connectors and it can automatically parse out content from email and enter into SharePoint as data.