# Sharepoint cannot see my mails?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-server

I tried to save my mails in SharePoint document library. I made all configurations like a link below.

http://sharepointquester.com/2013/09/04/configuring-incoming-email-on-a-sharepoint-2013-document-library/

But when I test the system, there isn't any item in document library. What do you think?
Thanks.

Comment: Is your email appears in the "C:\inetpub\mailroot\Drop" folder?

Comment: As Rusian said, if you are configured correctly, you can watch the email come through in the Drop folder. The SPTimer should then pick it up and direct to a doc lib

Answer (score 1):

Did you also do the exchange configuration part? Please refer to this excellent howto:
http://sharepointgeorge.com/2010/configuring-incoming-email-sharepoint-2010/

It describes SharePoint2010 & Exchange2010 but also applies 100% to SharePoint 2013. If you use Exchange 2013 your way to configure will differ, because it has a new web-based interface.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this can be considered a [duplicate question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/98764/email-into-a-list-on-2013-sharepoint-online), since the wording is different.  [Mail enabled lists](http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/809.aspx) are [not available](http://www.spmarketplace.com/blog/sharepoint-online-tips-for-getting-around-limitations) in [SharePoint Online](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/msonline/en-US/73673deb-04e8-4a27-a825-fe3b58683135/email-enabled-listslibraries-in-sharepoint-office-365?forum=onlineservicessharepoint).  An alternative is using [Site Mailboxes](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-help/overview-use-a-site-mailbox-to-collaborate-with-your-team-HA103927690.aspx) or [third-party add-ons](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2012/08/options-sharepoint-onlineemail-enabled-document-libraries-lists/).